# spark.memory.fraction control driver storage memory too?

Tags: apache-spark, configuration, driver

1. Background

   - Spark configuration

     ```scala
     val spark = SparkSession.builder().appName("wednesday_predict")
       .enableHiveSupport()
       .config("spark.memory.fraction", "0.2") // this also control storage memory in driver
       .config("spark.memory.storageFraction", "0.8")
       .config("spark.worker.ui.retainedExecutors", "100")
       .config("spark.worker.ui.retainedDrivers", "100")
       .getOrCreate()
     ```
   - Spark submit commands

     ```
     spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client  --driver-memory 7g 
     --executor-memory 16g --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 25  --class  genderPredict_dau 
     /data1/airflow/myscripts/userprofile/mlTag/predictionGender/gender_predlabel_2.11-0.1.jar
     ```
2. Problem

   I need to set a very large driver-memory which is 7g in order to get 1.2g storage memory in driver(see Spark UI below). otherwise, I get less storage memory in driver

   [image: Spark UI]
3. Possible reasons

   I find there is a connection between parameter `spark.memory.fraction` and storage memory in driver. when i set spark.memory.fraction equals to 0.2, driver-memory is 7g, the real storage memory in Spark UI for driver which is 1.2g just like spark.memory.fraction (0.2) * driver-memory (7g). In order to prove my guess, i change the spark.memory.fraction to 0.1, then the real storage memory for driver in Spark UI shows 660MB.
4. How?

   How can I set a lower "driver-memory"(like 2g) but get more storage memory (like 1g) in driver?

Comment: ok. i have update my post. now the only image is about sparkUI